# Show annotation like iPhone maps application when zoom MKMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm developing a iOS Map application. My concern is when user zoom In/ zoom out the map by default there are couple of places(like it will show some coffee shops,restaurants,etc... with respective icons for each) will be highlighting based on the location/region user perform zoom . In iPhone menu Maps application When user tap on any of those icons, it will show annotation with the name of place user tapped and the reviews of that place (like coffee shop,restaurant,etc..). If the same tap perform on my iOS application I'm not able to see any annotation and it will like disable not taking any actions. Can any one please help me on how can I show annotation like the way how iPhone menu Maps application showing? 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but that won't be possible ! Apple didn't allow developers to get their hands on these features.

As you can see in another application from Apple : Find My Friends, nothing would happen if you tap on these native annotations.

You can only play with these annotations in the native Apple Maps application.